# Outlook MailItem - Determine if the item is sent or received

Tags: vba, outlook, mailitem

In VBA, How do you identify whether an Outlook MailItem is Sent or Received?

Answer (score 1):

This seems general enough:

```
Public Enum MailItemStatus
  Sent
  Received
  Draft
End Enum

Public Function getMailStatus(mItem as Mailitem) as MailItemStatus
  if not mItem.sender is nothing then
    If mItem.Sender.Address = Application.Session.CurrentUser.Address Then
      if mItem.sent then
        'Item is sent
        getMailStatus = MailItemStatus.Sent
      else
        'Item is draft
        getMailStatus = MailItemStatus.Draft
      end if
    else
      'Item is received
      getMailStatus = MailItemStatus.Received
    end if
  else
    'Item is draft???
    getMailStatus = MailItemStatus.Draft
  end if
end function
```

Comment: Put code that does not work in the question. Possible responders can fix your non-working code and put that fixed code in an answer post. Perhaps if you delete this post yourself it will remain deleted.

Comment: @niton as far as I am concerned this works and therefore is an answer. There may be more direct methods which are more advantageous, but that doesn't affect the validity of this as an answer.

Comment: `if mItem.sender is nothing then` how can you then try to get `mItem.Sender.Address` in the next line?

Comment: Wooops, clearly indeed. Thanks for pointing out the error. Didn't spot that when I wrote it last night

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Public Enum MailItemStatus
  Sent
  Received
  Draft
End Enum


' Following the poster's Enum idea:

Public Function getMailStatus(mItem As MailItem) As MailItemStatus

    If mItem.Sent Then

        If mItem.Sender.Address = Session.CurrentUser.Address Then
            getMailStatus = MailItemStatus.Sent

        Else    'Item sent by someone who is not you
            getMailStatus = MailItemStatus.Received
        End If

    Else    'Item has not been sent

        getMailStatus = MailItemStatus.Draft

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Makes sense to use `mItem.sent` directly instead of checking mItem.sender is nothing. Thanks for simplifying :) I did also find there are like 3 statuses. `mItem.Saved`, `mItem.Posted` and `mItem.Sent` I'm unsure what `posted` means though...

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to do that, the only workaround is checking the `MailItem.ReceivedByName` property (or any of the other `ReceivedBy*` properties)- it will return an empty string for the messages from the Sent Items folder sent by the current user. For the received messages, it will return a non-empty value.

Comment: I hear `ReceivedByName` doesn't work when the sender is outside the business (and thus only has an email), though would have to verify this...

Comment: ReceivedByXYZ properties have nothing to do with the sender - they are related to the user *receiving* the message. Keep in mind that the Outlook user can have multiple identities (e.g. in case of multiple POP3 accounts delivering to the same store).

Comment: if I print the `item.ReceivedByName` for items in my sent folder, they state my name, even though I was not one of the recipients. Items i have received, also state my name (as expected). So `ReceivedByName` doesn't appear to function at all as required for me (office 2013)

Comment: Is that what you see in Outlook Spy (click the Item button, select the ReceivedByName property)? How were the messages sent? In my environment, for both Exchange and POP3/SMTP accounts, that property is null.

Comment: not sure about Outlook Spy. I just used VBA to print the property of the selected item. I did also check the locals window (which I assume is similar to Outlook Spy) which confirmed the data on my end. Not sure what environment our IT uses though...

Comment: Just tried again with the following code: https://hastebin.com/amovizabed.css Can confirm it was my name as the result of all calls to that function, whether they were sent or received.